# Error Installing parcel showing error at parcel\watcher and at node-gyp rebuild

Tags: javascript, parcel

1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\My sites\Music Website\node_modules@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.0 | win32 | ia32
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.1 found at "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS using VS2022 (17.8.34525.116) found at:
npm ERR! gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community"
npm ERR! gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm ERR! gyp info spawn C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\My sites\Music Website\node_modules\@parcel\watcher\build\config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.11.0\include\node\common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\node-gyp\Cache\20.11.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\Users\\USER\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.11.0\\<(target_arch)\\node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\My sites\Music Website\node_modules\@parcel\watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\My sites\Music Website\node_modules\@parcel\watcher\build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\My sites\Music Website\node_modules@parcel\watcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess. (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:271:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\My sites\Music Website\node_modules@parcel\watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-02-06T18_23_39_568Z-debug-0.log

Error trying to install parcel

i ran npm  i parcel --save-dev
but it was giving me errors which appeared to be coming from parcel\watcher and also node-gyp rebuild

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with the `@parcel/watcher` throwing an error npm `ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found`. I found a workaround by overriding it on `package.json`

```
"overrides": {
    "@parcel/watcher": "2.1.0"
},
```

[details here](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-app-template-remix/issues/543#issuecomment-1933288207)